# Run Sickbeard behind NGINX

Tags: server, proxy, nginx

I've been at this for so long now, trying to get my sickbeard to run behind nginx and having no luck at all, excuse my noobness.

Here's what I've tried.

I have sickbeard installed in[b] /opt/sickbeard[/b]

Inside the **config.ini** file within the sicbeard directory, I have edited to **web_root** variable to equal **/opt/sickbeard**

In the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file, this is what I have:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name    http://server.example.com;
        location /sickbeard {
            proxy_pass    http://server.example.com:8081/opt/sickbeard;
        }
    }
}
```

This just doesn't work even the slightest, what am i doing wrong?

Shannon

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct to assume that you want to use nginx just as a proxy to sickbeard server?
If so then there are a couple of things to correct here:

1. web_root in config.ini defines a path on the webserver that sickbeard expects to receive in HTTP query (look here: https://code.google.com/p/sickbeard/wiki/AdvancedSettings). Therefore given that you've set up nginx to re-route queries on /sickbeard, the web_root should be 'sickbeard'.
2. The 'proxy_pass' in nginx config is also incorrect. It should contain the URL at which you have your sickbeard running directly (which I think in your case is the URL without opt/sickbeard). I presume if you try to open your 'proxy_path' URL in a browser, you will get a HTTP 404.

There is a nice tutorial at nginx website (http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy) so you might want to check that too.